# emit is not working when calling on a separate android thread

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, qt, qml

Sorry for my english.

There is a code that running on android on a separate Thread (Java Code) like this:

```
public class ClientThread extends Thread 
{
    public void run()
    {
        MainActivity.nativeMethod(); // not working
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends QtActivity
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static MainActivity _instance = null;
    private static ClientThread _clientThread = null;

    public MainActivity()
    {
        _instance = this;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        nativeMethod(); // working

        _clientThread = new ClientThread();
        _clientThread.start();

    }

    public static native void nativeMethod();
}
```

And there is C++ bridge for that:

```
class TestObject : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit TestObject(QObject *parent = 0);
    static TestObject *getInstance();

Q_SIGNALS:
    void nativeMethod();

public Q_SLOTS:

};

static void nativeMethod(JNIEnv *, jclass)
{
        qDebug() << "works threaded or non-threaded calls But not below on threaded call.";
    emit TestObject::getInstance()->nativeMethod();
}
```

Also a QML connection:

```
import TestObjectPackage 1.0

Connections
{
    target: TestObjectPackage.testObjectInstance
    onNativeMethod:
    {
        console.log("QML received signal!");
    }
}
```

jniNativeMethod calls every time but emit not sending signal to QML on sepearate thread. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Qt can send signals over different threads. It does book-keeping which object "belongs" to which thread and signals are passed accordingly.

However you need to make sure that the receiving thread actually processes incoming signals. This is by either installing a Qt mainloop in the receiving thread or by querying the Qt queue manually.

See http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects for all the details.